# Laravel: How do you pass data to a blade.php?

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-blade, laravel-livewire

I am having difficulty in understanding how to pass data to a `.blade`. I want to pass the users' username `($user)` to a dashboard component. Here's a few things I've tried:

```
return view('livewire.dashboard', ['user'=>'$user']);
return view('livewire.dashboard', compact('$user'));
return view('livewire.dashboard'->with('user',$user));
```

But then I realized that the class I was trying to pass the user info from didn't know what the user variable is. Here is the class (Dashboard.php):

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;
use Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException;
use Livewire\Component;

class Dashboard extends Component
{
    /**
     * @return View|Factory
     * @throws BindingResolutionException
     */
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.dashboard');
    }
}
```

And here is my web.php file:

```
use App\Http\Livewire\Dashboard;
use App\Http\Livewire\User;

    // Dashboard
    Route::get('/', Dashboard::class)->name('dashboard');
    // I have also tried something like 'Route get user' here, also didn't work

     // User routes
    Route::prefix('/users')->group(function () {
        Route::get('/', User\Index::class)->name('users.index');
        Route::get('/create', User\Create::class)->name('users.create');
        Route::get('/{user}', User\Edit::class)->name('users.edit');
    });
```

I'm having difficulty understanding how components/classes/blade tamplates communicate with each other. How can I pass the username of the person currently logged in to my dashboard.blade.php file? It looks like this:

```
    @isset($user)
    Hallo {{ $user->name }},
    @endisset
</div>
<div>Willkommen im Formular-Editor!</div>
<div>Neue Formulare kannst du über den Tab "Editor" oben in der Leiste anlegen. Hier kannst Du auch bestehende Formulare bearbeiten.</div>
```

An explanation as well as a solution would be appreciated, as I really don't understand how Laravel works. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass them

```
<livewire:show-post :user="$user">
```

[**In Laravel Way**](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/views)

```
public function render()
{
    return view('livewire.dashboard', ['user' => auth()->user()]);
}
```

Read More [Official LiveWire Doc](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/rendering-components)

---

### Apart from all

***Laravel is a Well designed Framework***. So passing the logged-in users here and there(fetch in the controller and pass to view with `$user`), you can directly access using the [`auth()`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-auth) helper.

**In view**

```
auth()->id();
auth()->user();
```

Comment: Thank you! Solved it like this:
 public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.dashboard', ['user'=>auth()->user()]);
    }

Comment: Don't pass it through the livewire. Remove it, and still can accessible in your blade files using `auth()->user()`

Answer (score 2):

As you are using Livewire, you probably want to take advantage of [data binding](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/properties#data-binding) (one of the benifits of Livewire).

What you can do is define a `$user` property on your `Dashboard` component that you can then access in the `dashboard.blade.php` view.

Your `Dashboard` component might look as follows (I've omitted code for brevity)

```
class Dashboard extends Component
{
    public $user;

    /*
     * The mount() function is Livewires equivalent of __construct()
     */
    public function mount()
    {
        $this->user = Auth::user();
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.dashboard');
    }
}
```

Then in your view you would simply access `$user`

```
Hallo {{ $user->name }}
```

Comment: @AbdullaNilam Well yeah, I did mention that in my answer and `Dashboard` is - as per the original question - a `Livewire Component`.

Answer (score 0):

In a more simpler way, you can use compact as you are using in second step. The only change you need to remove $ from user variable.

eg.

```
return view('livewire.dashboard', compact('user'));
```